# mongoose load a json removes Schema Types ObjectId data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to load `.json` files for unit tests using mongoose.

When I load the json file into a model, it removes any `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` from the object, but I need them.

Example Schema:

```js
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  userId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
})
```

My JSON file:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "XXXXXX" }
  "title": "Post title",
  "userId": { "$oid": "XXXXXX" }
}
```

After I load it into a mongoose object, the userId disappears:

```js
const postJson = require('./data/post.json')
const post = new mongoose.models.Post(postJson)
console.log(post)
// Prints => { _id: "XXXX", title: "Post title" }
```

I obviously need the `userId` to test my function. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or get the whole output?

*(Ps: I need to convert it to a mongoose object because the function I'm testing uses `post.userId.equals(user._id)`*